# android button listener not working

Tags: android, button, android-fragments, layout

I have a fragment which has the layout_a. Under that fragment I dynamically add a textview and a button which is part of layout_b. I am unable to get the button(myButton part of layout_b) listener to work. I have other buttons which are part of layout_a and are working. To use the button listener in layout_b I am doing to the following steps.

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater in, ViewGroup vgroup, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        testView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_b, container, false);
         ...
         myButton = (Button) testView.findViewById(R.id.my_button);
         ...
}
private void configureSuggestedEmailButton() {
        myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Log.i("test", "click");
                ...

            }
        });
    }
```

### Do I need to do anything different since the fragment layout is layout_a, and the button is in layout_b ?

Updated Code:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater in, ViewGroup vgroup, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         //this view is used to setup buttons from layout_a, current activity has this layout
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_a, container, false);
         //this view is used to manage to the layout_b
            testView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_b, container, false);
            myButton = (Button) testView.findViewById(R.id.my_button);

            configureSuggestedEmailButton();
    }
private void configureSuggestedEmailButton() {
            myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    Log.i("test", "click");


                }
            });
   }

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/layout_b"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">


        <Button
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:id="@+id/my_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="30dip"
            android:text="Yes"
            android:textSize="10sp"

            />

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: So you are adding this new part into the layout_a right? and where do you do that, in your code?

Comment: @Diyoda I have a function call which does the following 
`LinearLayout row = (LinearLayout) getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.layout_b, null);
 LinearLayout eLayout = (LinearLayout) editTextField.getParent(); eLayout.addView(errorRow, someIndex); 
...`
 Button shows up on the screen, but the listener is not responding. My take is that button listener is not attached to the fragment

Comment: Can you update the question with all the relevant code, I will help you for sure

Comment: @diyoda I updated the code, please let me know if you have need more info.

Comment: Look at my code. there can be syntax issue, I did not use my IDE to write this up. I want to convey the idea. Is this the way you already do it? I hope you missed any parts of your code which you thought irrelevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is your complete code. Where is your return statement in you `onCreateView` method.

Here,

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater in, ViewGroup vgroup, Bundle savedInstanceState){
               //this view is used to setup buttons from layout_a, current activity has this layout
                view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_a, container, false);

                // Here get the reference to the UI element which you want to inject the layout_b
                injectReferece = (LinearLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.injectElement);// In this case Assume that the the hoder of the layout_b is a `LinearLayout`, You have to specify that in your layout_a with the id injectElement(In this example ok :))



                //this view is used to manage to the layout_b
                testView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_b, container, false);
                myButton = (Button) testView.findViewById(R.id.my_button);

                configureSuggestedEmailButton();

                // Then you actually add it, 
                injectReferece.addView(myButton );
                return view;
}
```

I see that you inflate the layout_a, and you have to return that at the end of the onCreateView method. But before that (returning the `view` variabe) You are again inflating the layout_b.

But, you have to add that into the inflated layout_a (in other words object hierarchy of layout_a in memory) using `addView()` method

Comment: that is actually my mistake, I do return the layout_a at the end of the onCreateView, but I didn't add the secondlayout to that view. Would I need to use a ViewGroup? Or is there a way to add the second view to the first view.

Comment: As i said, add a specific location in your layout_a (`injectElement` or what ever). and reference that (`injectReferece`)  then do  `injectReferece.addView(myButton );`. I explained it in my comments in the code.

Comment: i gave you an upvote, but I will become visible once I have 15 points (referring to the popup message I got). Again thanks for your advice. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater in, ViewGroup vgroup, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    testView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_b, container, false);
     ...
     myButton = (Button) testView.findViewById(R.id.my_button);

     myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.i("test", "click");
            ...
        }
    });
     ...
}
 private void configureSuggestedEmailButton() {

}
```

Comment: Hey, I am calling the method configureSuggestedEmailButton()  under onCreateView. Problem still exist. Thanks for the advice.